Why connection to mysql is worked but columns are not showed in SSIS source odbc component?
when I connect to mysql database with odbc source component on SSIS it worked and tables are shown, but when I select a table and go to columns, no column is showed.
I have mysql connector net 8.2 and mysql connector odbc 8.2

If anyone have the same problem and solve it or have the solution please help me.
When I click on "Apercu.." this error appear, I don't know if it's related..
enter image description here

It can be a permission on database issue, are you logged in as admin?

No, with another user. But it worked  with my friend for the same db and the same login

Can you try to connect from another client?

The same problem. I added an image, please check it if the problem is related..

Try follow the official guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16
